# Radio buttons to allow toggle of data in a drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down box of which the content is dynamically generated by a JSON file. There is a lot of content within the drop down box, however the
content within can all be categorised 4 types. So I have added radio buttons to toggle the data displayed in the drop down box accordingly.

I have knocked up some html to toggle between data that is manually entered into the drop down, but I am unsure on how to toggle data that is dynamically generated.

The current code is as shown below. Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
var listA = [{name:'ALM_1', value:'ALM_1'}, {name:'ALM_2', value:'ALM_2'}, {name:'ALM_3', value:'ALM_3'}];

var listB = [{name:'BR_1', value:'BR_1'}, {name:'BR_2', value:'BR_2'}, {name:'BR_3', value:'BR_3'}];

var listC = [{name:'BUG_1', value:'BUG_1'}, {name:'BUG_2', value:'BUG_2'}, {name:'BUG_3', value:'BUG_3'}];

var listD = [{name:'Feat_1', value:'Feat_1'}, {name:'Feat_2', value:'Feat_2'}, {name:'Feat_3', value:'Feat_3'}];

$(document).ready( function() {
  $("input[name='chk']").on('change',function() {

      if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'ALM')
      {
        $('#describe').empty()
        $.each(listA, function(index, value) {
         $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
        });                  
      }
      else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'BR')
      {
        $('#describe').empty()
        $.each(listB, function(index, value) {
         $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
        }); 
      }
      else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'BUG')
      {
        $('#describe').empty()
        $.each(listC, function(index, value) {
         $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
        }); 
      }
       else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'FEAT')
      {
        $('#describe').empty()
        $.each(listD, function(index, value) {
         $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
        }); 
      }

  });
});
```

Comment: How Radio buttons are created ?

Comment: Hi Rayon, they are created in the html. Something like this;   "<li><input type="radio" id="class" name="chk" option value="ALM" id="change" onclick="ALM_Test"('patternstable')" checked>ALM <br/></li>"  cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> I am unsure on how to toggle data that is dynamically generated.

To deal with dynamically generated data you should use event delegation `on()` :

```
$("body").on('change', 'input[name="chk"]', function() {
    //Your code here
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Zakaria, thanks for your help. How would this work with my current code? For example how would it know which data each radio button should show. cheers